# How would you build a cron that empties the mail in all mailboxes?

Tags: cron, mail-command

I am new to Unix here.

We have some mailboxes that are taking up an incredible amount of space and I'm trying to figure out a way to delete all mail that has been in the box for 30 days. Most of what I look up, deals with just one mailbox.

I haven't done much in this area yet and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to totally remove all mail every 30 days (so even mail which arrived 2 seconds ago gets deleted), or do you want to remove items of mail over 30 days old from all mailboxes.

Comment: I see my miscommunication.  I would like to remove mail that has been in the system for 30 days.

Comment: Next one, can you confirm how mail is stored on the server, is it mbox (traditional, everyone has a single `/var/spool/mail/username` file), or Maildir (where everyone has a directory, in which individual items of mail are single files).  I'm assuming the former, but better to know for definite.  Also, which UNIX or Linux distribution?

Comment: It is the former.  As far as the distribution I'm afraid when I try and proc/version it says it's denied...unsure of why.

Comment: Ah well, `archivemail` looked useful, but new versions don't allow `root` to expire other users mail files, which seems a backward step.  Do you have an example for one user that you know works, but you just want to use it on all the mail files?

Comment: Well I used this earlier to test on my account:

' cat /dev/null >/var/spool/mail/<username> '

Comment: Okay, that just empties the entire mailbox, that's easy to do, but it's not what you appear to be asking for.  If you just want to do that, @MelBurslan's answer works.

Comment: Well that's actually all I've been able to do so far.  I can't figure out how to set any age of the mail or by date (such as 30 days prior to deletion).  Right now my only option that I can work with is to manually remove all mail from every user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to clear out all of the mailbox contents except maybe `root` and some other protected user, you can use something like this:

```
for mbox in $(ls /var/spool/mail/*|grep -v -e root -e protecteduser);do >${mbox};done
```

and schedule it in cron to run on the 1st day of each month with

```
crontab -e
```

insert the following line at the end of the crontab:

```
0 2 1 * * /path/to/mailbox/cleaner/script
```

this will make the script run on the first day of each month at 2 AM

On the other hand if you need to clean mail which is older than 30 days in each mailbox, it will need a totally different approach. If this is your intention, please update your original post.